# Changing backgrounds over time

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

How can I change the background colour over time in SpriteKit? Like animating the background, the current background should slowly fade out over the other background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create special scene properties for that

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) SKSpriteNode *background1;
@property (nonatomic,retain) SKSpriteNode *background2;
```

Just init nodes and add them to the scene. Then animate fade in/out.

```
[self.background1 runAction:[SKAciton fadeAlphaTo:0 duration:0.3]]; 
[self.background2 runAction:[SKAciton fadeAlphaTo:1 duration:0.3]];
```

Comment: Thank you . I have a small doubt , does background1 automatically gets deallocated from the scene after fading out ?

Comment: No, it won't deallocate until you remove it from the scene by `[self.background1 removeFromParent]` and set class property to nil `self.background1=nil` (it links to the variable reference count, read more about Automatic Reference Counting).